# Google map pin click is not working after applying css3 zoom property

Tags: css, google-maps, css-transitions

Google map pin click is not working after applying css3 zoom property. I am not able to click on it.

I want to apply zoom property.

```
        <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false"></script>
            <script>
    // This example displays a marker at the center of Australia.
    // When the user clicks the marker, an info window opens.

    function initialize() {
        var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-25.363882,131.044922);
        var mapOptions = {
            zoom: 4,
            center: myLatlng
        };

        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

        var contentString = '<div id="content">'+
                '<div id="siteNotice">'+
                '</div>'+
                '<h1 id="firstHeading" class="firstHeading">Uluru</h1>'+
                '<div id="bodyContent">'+
                '<p><b>Uluru</b>,</p>'+
                '</div>'+
                '</div>';

        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                content: contentString
        });

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: myLatlng,
                map: map,
                title: 'Uluru (Ayers Rock)'
        });
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
            infowindow.open(map,marker);
        });
    }

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

            </script>
    <style>
    html, body, #map-canvas {
                    height: 100%;
                    margin: 0px;
                    padding: 0px
                }

    #map-canvas{
            zoom: 0.7;
            -moz-transform: scale(0.7);
            -webkit-transform: scale(0.7);

    }
    </style>
        <body>
            <div id="map-canvas"></div>
        </body>
```

Can someone tell me why i am not getting hand pointer after applying css3 zoom property.

Comment: [jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/BHhrF/)

Answer (score 0):

please refer the link. 
http://jsfiddle.net/6TkY4/1/

```
var mapOptions = {
                     center: new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude),
                      zoom: 8,
                     mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP

                 };

If you want to change zoom size, then increase zoom property value in mapOptions.
```

Also please refer your fiddle example works now.

http://jsfiddle.net/BHhrF/1/

Don't set div height in % value. Please use pixel value. or else use outer div with pixel. Inner div height in %. It will work.

Comment: Could you please tell what is wrong with applying css3 zoom property?

Comment: what is the need of zoom property here?. If you want map zooming, then use map zoom property.It will also increase div zooming property.

Comment: So the exact scenario is, when user zoom in the page, i want to resize map in such a way that it looks exactly same as it was when page was un-zoomed (Zoom -level 1). Even if i change the map zoom property, map control and other fonts will be coming in zoomed state that is why i want to use css zoom or css scale.